# How to prevent unnatural wrapping of text with multiply elements in HTML

Tags: html, css

How can I make the following text wrap in a natural way?

```html
<li>
    200g &nbsp;
    <a href="LINK">
       Fullkornspasta
    </a>
    , spaghetti
</li>
```

This is how the text currently wraps:

[image]

This is how I would like the text to wrap:

(I would like the "," to be at the end of the line)

[image]

Comment: Try making your HTML code one line

Comment: Don't put whitespace between `,` and link

Comment: @IvanBeliakov it's irrelevant

Comment: Please share your CSS because this [cannot be reproduced](https://jsbin.com/dexiweh/edit?html,css,output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using several lines for text inside an HTML element can cause undesired effects, such as spaces. So it is better to make it one line. Compare these:

```html
<li>
   200g &nbsp;
   <a href="LINK">
      Fullkornspasta
   </a>
   , spaghetti
</li>

<li>
   200g &nbsp;
   <a href="LINK">
      Fullkornspasta
   </a>, spaghetti
</li>

<li>
   200g &nbsp;
   <a href="LINK">Fullkornspasta</a>
   , spaghetti
</li>

<li>
   200g &nbsp;
   <a href="LINK">Fullkornspasta</a>, spaghetti
</li>


<li>200g &nbsp;<a href="LINK">Fullkornspasta</a>, spaghetti</li>
```

Comment: Thanks! This was ultimately the issue, me having `, spaghetti` on a new line added a space.

Answer (score 1):

```css
div {
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
  background: #aaa;
}

.nowrap{
  white-space: nowrap
}
```

```html
<div>
  <li>
    200g &nbsp;
    <span class="nowrap">
      <a href="LINK">
        Fullkornspasta
      </a>,
    </span>
      spaghetti
   </li>
</div>
```

so you wanted this result? I know it's little hacky but I have no better solution for line breaks between elements.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<li>200g <a href="LINK">Fullkornspasta</a>, spaghetti,</li>
```

And please note if you plan on modifying where it says "200g" and where it says spaghetti you'd have to give "200g" a separate class as the following code below would not just make "200g" red but also where it says the word "spaghetti"

```
<style>
li{
color:red;
}
</style>
```